# Down-sampling with numpy

Tags: python, numpy, statistics, scipy, sampling

I have an 1D array A that represents categorical data (where each entry is the number of element of a certain category):

```
A = array([ 1, 8, 2, 5, 10, 32, 0, 0, 1, 0])
```

and I am trying to write a function **sample(A, N)** to generate an array **B** that contains N elements generated by randomly drawing elements from A (keeping the categories):

```
>>> sample(A, 20)
array([ 1, 3, 0, 1, 4, 11, 0, 0, 0, 0])
```

I wrote this:

```
def sample(A, N):
    AA = A.astype(float).copy()
    Z = zeros(A.shape)
    for _ in xrange(N):
        drawn = random.multinomial(1, AA/AA.sum())
        Z = Z + drawn
        AA = AA - drawn
    return Z.astype(int)
```

Probably it is quite naive, is there a better/faster way to do it? Maybe using some fast numpy function?
Edit: It was not clear: it has to be without replacement!!!

Comment: Maybe I'm totally wrong here, but is there a reason you're not just using `random.multinomial(N, A/A.sum())` instead of your whole function?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by *keeping the categories*? Also, it looks like you are drawing *without* replacement?

Comment: @hgazibara When one element is drawn, the probability of drawing that element again should decrease. `random.multinomial(N, A/A.sum())` would represent taking items and putting them back after.

Comment: Aaah! You are attempting to sample from the distribution represented by the *histogram* `A`

Comment: Your code doesn't look like it can work this way. I assume you would want to replace `Z = Z + drawn` with `Z[drawn] += 1`?

Comment: @eickenberg `Z[drawn] += 1` would add 1 to the first and second element of Z. `Z = Z + drawn` works fine. `Z[drawn == 1] += 1` would also work

Comment: @M4rtini exactly I was just writing the same

Comment: Aah, true, my bad -- I thought it gives back indices. Forget my last comment(s)

Comment: From your comments below, your non-numpy code is probably fastest for your application (a small-sized sample drawn from a really big population). Sampling without replacement relatively few times from a large population is the exact limit where vectorization will not help you much. All three answers involve writing out the full population.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

faster than the other's as far as i can see. But probably uses more memory.

```
import random 
from collections import Counter

def sample2(A,N):
    distribution = [i for i, j in enumerate(A) for _ in xrange(j)]
    sample = Counter(random.sample(distribution, N))
    return [sample[i] for i in xrange(len(A))]


In [52]: A = np.random.randint(0, 100, 500)

In [53]: %timeit sample(A, 100) #Original
100 loops, best of 3: 2.71 ms per loop

In [54]: %timeit sample2(A, 100) #my function
1000 loops, best of 3: 914 µs per loop

In [55]: %timeit sample3(A, 100) #sftd function
100 loops, best of 3: 8.33 ms per loop
```

Comment: Does not work for me... I get an error! Is random.sample the numpy.random.random_sample function?

Comment: No, it's from random in the standard library. And this is one (of many) reasons, for why you should avoid `from numpy import *`

Comment: Very fast! This is the solution I was looking for!!! One more thing: is there a way to optimize it further memory-wise using a lazy generator instead of `distribution = [i for i, j in enumerate(A) for _ in xrange(j)]`?

Comment: @Gioelelm not as far as i know, i tried using a generator expression for the distribution. But `random.sample` does not seem to be able to take a generator as input.

Answer (score 2):

This may not be the most elegant solution, but it's about 3x as fast. It uses [`numpy.random.choice`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html), which has a Boolean replace option (in this case set to `False` - i.e. without replacement). The rest of the code is to:

- Set up the array of choices, which contains `A[n]` counts of the index `n`, e.g. for `A=[2,0,3,1]` you'd get `choices=[0,0,2,2,2,3]`. Note that each of these will have equal probability so no need to create a probability array.
- Convert the values chosen by the numpy function call into the output array required. Each element of the `vals` array will be an index picked from the `choices` array, so you need to add 1 to the appropriate element of `B` for each of these chosen indices.

I hope that makes sense! Here is the code:

```
def sample_2(A, N):
    # Create array of choices (indicies)
    choices = []
    for n in xrange(len(A)):
        for _ in xrange(A[n]):
            choices.append(n)
    # Randomly choose from these indicies
    vals = numpy.random.choice(choices, N, False)
    # Count up the chosen indicies
    B = numpy.zeros(len(A), dtype=int)
    for index in xrange(N):
        B[vals[index]] += 1
    return B
```

Speed test results for 10000 calls of each function:

```
Original: 3.0517 s
Method_2: 0.9968 s
```

Comment: Similar to my solution! If you swap out your second loop for `np.histogram`, does it help?

Comment: This is fast only for small A. Try the comparison with `A = random.randint(0, 100, 3000)`

Comment: Yep, you're right. Seems like M4rtini may have a nicer solution for larger arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would do it:

```
def sample(A, N):
        population = np.zeros(sum(A))
        counter = 0
        for i, x in enumerate(A):
                for j in range(x):
                        population[counter] = i
                        counter += 1

        sampling = population[np.random.randint(0, len(population), N)]
        return np.histogram(sampling, bins = np.arange(len(A)+1))[0]
```

What we're doing is building a population defined by the histogram A and then randomly sampling from it. If the real-world case has N large and sum(A) small, and/or you need to sample A many times for a fixed A, this should be better. What you'd do is to build the population corresponding to A outside of the function call and define `sample(population, N)` as just the last two lines of the above.

Comment: Another concern is that if the numbers in a real-world A are big, your population will get too expensive in terms of memory. Be warned.

Comment: This function does not do what I want. For example if I do `A = array([1,8,2,5,10,32,0,0,1,0])` and `sample(A, 20)` I can get: `array([ 2,  6,  0,  1,  0, 11,  0,  0,  0,  0])` Look at the first element!!! it  has been **created**

Comment: Well you'll need to be clearer about what you want then. I get `array([ 0  4  0  3  2 11  0  0  0  0])` from my call, modulo the random seed, which seems identical to the requested behavior.

Comment: Are you asking for sampling without replacement then??? That is a critical part of the question.

Comment: Then switch np.random.randint with np.random.choice, and you're done.

Comment: but then I get `ValueError: a must be greater than 0`